# TCP client hangs on read while read from inputStream

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, byte

I have code TCP Server which sending a file and I am trying to save to file this bytes from client but the client freeze on read. Program dont give any exception and it is hard to debug.

Server Code:

```
private void byteSend(Result result) {
        try {
            BufferedOutputStream outToClient = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            File file = new File(Service.getInstance().getServer().getShareDirectory() + "/" + result.getData().toString().replace("__", " "));
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];

            FileInputStream fis;

            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);

                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                bis.read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
                outToClient.write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            outToClient.flush();
            outToClient.close();

            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Client code:

```
// create file input stream
                    InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();

                    // create new data input stream
                    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);

                    // available stream to be read
                    int length = dis.available();

                    // create buffer
                    byte[] buf = new byte[length];

                    // read the full data into the buffer
                    dis.readFully(buf);

                    // for each byte in the buffer
                    for (byte b:buf)
                    {
                        // convert byte to char
                        char c = (char)b;

                        // prints character
                        System.out.print(c);
                    }
                    break;
```

How to resolve this problem? Can you give me some tips?

Comment: Whats hard to debug? This is single threaded code with a single execution path

Comment: Client gives length = 0;

Comment: You are assuming you always read the whole buffer size when the minimum is 1. i.e. you have to use the length returned by `read(...)`

Comment: But when i connect to server with telnet it receive file properly.

Comment: Can you give me example?

Comment: dis.available() returns the amount of data which can be read without a system call.  This could be less than the size (if not all the data has been downloaded) or more than the size if there is any data after the file.

Comment: There is no point using a buffered stream if you are reading into a buffer which is larger than the buffer in the stream.

Comment: @PeterLawrey with read() i always receive timeout. Why?

Comment: @PeterLawrey from telnet it works.

Comment: Classic misuse of `available()`. There is a warning in the Javadoc specifically *against* the way you're using it. @PeterLawrey It returns the amount of data that can be read without *blocking,* not 'without a system call'.